# If I disable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED, my request is still denied

Tags: node.js, fetch

I am disabling Node from rejecting self signed certificates and making a request.

```
const { USER, PW } = process.env;

const b64 = new Buffer(`${VP_API_USER}:${VP_API_PW}`).toString("base64");

const Authorization = `Basic ${b64}`;

const doFind = async url => {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
  const results = await fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization } })
    .then(r => (r.ok ? r.json() : Promise.reject(r)))
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;

  return results;
};
```

I am still being rejected.

```
{ FetchError: request to https://<url>:55544/contracts failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED <url>:55544
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/mjhamm75/Developer/sedd-monorepo/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:133:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'FetchError',
  message: 'request to https://<url>:55544/contracts failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED <url>:55544',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means the connection was refused. It doesn't seem to me like your problem is a TLS rejection.

Answer (score 4):

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;

line should go inside the callback (your then or catch before the return. because a promise gets resolved in the callback, but your line

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;

is written outside of it, even though it appears after the statement, it runs immediately without waiting for the callback.  so, your tls is effectively never disabled.

I hope this helps:)

Comment: `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'` is the correct command to run: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/42dbaed4605f44c393a057aad75a31cac1d0e5f5/lib/_tls_wrap.js#L1307

Answer (score 4):

Previous answer looks incorrect - await postpones execution of next line until promise will be resolved.
According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value) the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED value should be string '0' to disable TLS validation.

Comment: you are correct: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/42dbaed4605f44c393a057aad75a31cac1d0e5f5/lib/_tls_wrap.js#L1307

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it, if I had to reset the env var afterwards.

Using `.finally()` the statement will execute regardless of the outcome of the fetch.

```js
const doFind = async url => {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
  const results = await fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization } })
    .then(r => (r.ok ? r.json() : Promise.reject(r)))
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;
    });
  return results;
};
```